# JPA @sequenceGenerate @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I´m new on the JPA world and i´m having the following problem.

I have a class that have a generated classId. This class have a list of students and one of this column (in Student) is the classId.

I implemented this but the classId for Student Table appears null in the database (the rest it´s OK).

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

This is the code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class")
public class Class implements Serializable {

    private Long classId;

    private List<Student> student;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "class_id_gen", sequenceName = "seq_class_id", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "class_id_gen")
    @Column(name = "class_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "class", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        return this.Student;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The Class. 
     */
    private Class class;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    public Class getClass() {
        return this.class;
    }

}

Main:

Class class = null;

    UserTransaction.begin();

    class = new Class();

    class.setStudents(ListOfStudents);

    EntityManager.persist(class);

    UserTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asked every two days. The owner side of this bidirectional association is the side where there is **no** `mappedBy` attribute. This is the side that Hibernate uses to know if the relation exists or not.

You initialized one side of the association (`clazz.setStudents(...)`), but this side is not the owner side. So Hibernate doesn't know that the association axists and must be persisted.

You must initialize the other side: the owner side:

```
for (Student s : listOfStudents) {
    s.setClazz(clazz);
}
```